# Jmeter how to loop through a list of different properties in a single thread group or controller?

Tags: loops, jmeter

How to do a basic loop through different properties for a fixed set of controllers?  Loop controller runs a set group a certain number of times, does not use properties though.

I can do modules, and set the values to properties for multi thread group usage, but how to pass the next iteration of the property, and run the loop again?

```
property x
do module (points to controllers)
next property
```

Say I have a list of 44 characters, and I want to loop through those characters in a ${name} while I'm doing a test.  I'd very much not like to build 44 sets of controllers for one character change.

**Please Note** I cannot add extra files to my computer.  It has to work via the stock available controllers.  I'm using Jmeter 2.4 r961953

Thanks

Comment: at this point I'm building 44 sets of meta controllers, that run one module which runs a thread group.  I"m passing the changed character to each test.  C'mon Jmeter, just a simple loop?

Comment: and what if I wanted to do a set of tests, with properties of one then properties of another?  Normally this would be a loop within a loop. :(

Answer (score 11):

I will elaborate slightly more about the BeanShell method. My assumption is that you'd like to do it within one User Thread, if so my proposal would be:

Create a **Loop Controller**.

- Logic Controller->Loop Controller

Inside **Loop Controller** add following entries:

- Config Element -> Counter
- Preprocessors -> BeanShell preprocessor
- Sampler -> *yourSampler*

The **Counter** element will be used as an index that will be used to choose valid value from our array, hence we need to specify a `Reference Name` for the **Counter** - let's say that it will be `loopCounter`.

Now we have to switch to **BeanShell** preprocessor and define the array of values. A great thing is that we have `vars` variable available and it gives us CRUD access to variables used in the scenario:

```
String[] varArray = {"Value1", "Value2"};
idx = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("loopCounter"))-1;
vars.put("myVariable", varArray[idx]);
```

And for the final step, inside **mySampler** we can use a variable in a regular JMeter way : `${myVariable}`

[JMeter API](http://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) can be very helpfull if you want a more sophisticated solution.

Comment: Can i ask you here what should i put into 'Loop Controller' field, in order to tell 'Loop Controller' how many times to run?

Answer (score 2):

There are a handful of different ways to loop through different values without adding external files:

- Use beanshell controller, and write javascript to set your variable
- Use a counter to increment by one
- Use User Parameters

You can set it up so each loop gets a different value.

Check out the various [configuration controllers](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/component_reference.html#config_elements) to find one that works best for you.

EDIT:
I meant [user parameters](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Parameters), not user define variables.

**User Parameter**

You'd need one row per variable with 44 columns. Sorry for the confusion.

User Parameter Structure

```
test plan
 - Thread Group looped 44 times
 -- User parameter
 -- Request
```

**Beanshell Method**

Alternately, you could do an array in javascript in connection with a counter. The Beanshell samplers have access to Jmeter variables and properties, allowing the beanshell sampler to read the counter value. This may be a faster, cleaner way then using User Parameters.

Beanshell structure

```
test plan
 - Thread Group looped 44 times
 -- Counter
 -- Request
 ---- Beanshell pre-processor
```

Beanshell Pseudo code would be

```
def counter = value of Jmeter Counter
def array = array of values

declare  the variable "sampler_value" to be used by sampler
def sampler_value = array @ counter
```

**Counter with CharAt function**

If you only need to generate characters, you could use the [javascript function](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/functions.html#__javaScript) to utilize the function [charAt](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_charat.asp), using the value from the Counter.  Basic structure would be:
    test plan
     - Thread Group looped 44 times
     -- Counter
     -- Request

with the request using something like `${__javaScript(charAt(${counter}))` as the parameter value.  You may have to use JEXL instead of javaScript or evalVar/V/eval inside the charAt function.

Comment: No Javascript examples there.  Honestly I find the jakarta docs quite pointless.  So, I have a User Variables in the root of the Test Plan, then I have a Thread group I want to repeat 44 times, with one variable change each time.  Currently I have 44 thread groups all running one module, which is passed the new value each time.  This works but I am looking for a more easily managed loop.

Comment: Counter looks TG specific and doesn't eliminate the need for 44 TG's even with an increment.  It's not going to loop the iterations, only what the next TG uses. So wouldn't I still need 44 TG's ?

Comment: Am already using User defined properties and the setProperty command for the variables to use.  This is how the 44 TG's work.

Comment: last comment for a bit;  Can I make an array in the beanshell under javascript, then call Counter to be the means of calling the next index of the array?  Then make the Loop Controller use the array index value?

Comment: You can create an array in Beanshell to be used during your loop.  I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Went with CSV Data Set Config to load the different changes.  That works in that I can set the Loop Controller to 44 and it will do the job.  Now I don't want to hardcode the 44.  Not sure how to use Counter here.  Would be happy with a beanshell that tells me how many lines in the csv file (-1 for header) then use that var as the Loop Controller size.