# make 'n' requests in jmeter given an array of length 'n'

Tags: jmeter

i have this json `{"ProductCode": ["V28334","V16P2","V16P3", "test", "fake"]}`
and the url depends on the value of productCode, that is, the url is **https: \ ... \ ProductCode**

in this case I would like to execute this request 5 times (the length of the array), being the url https: \ ... \ V28334 for the first case,  https: \ ... \ V16P2 for the second case
[image]

Comment: Have you look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847812/jmeter-how-to-loop-through-a-list-of-different-properties-in-a-single-thread-gro, I believe you might find what you need there

Comment: Is the JSON `{"ProductCode": ["V28334","V16P2","V16P3", "test", "fake"]}` coming from  a response or you have it in a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First of all you need to extract these values from the [JSON Array](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp). In order to do this add a [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor) as a child of the request which returns the above JSON and configure it as follows:

   - Names of created variables: anything meaningful, i.e. `ProductCode`
   - JSON Path Expressions: `$.ProductCode.*`
   - Match No.: `-1`

     [image]

   it will give you the following JMeter Variables:

   ```
   ProductCode_1=V28334
   ProductCode_2=V16P2
   ProductCode_3=V16P3
   ProductCode_4=test
   ProductCode_5=fake
   ProductCode_matchNr=5
   ```
2. Then to iterate each and every variable add a [ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) and put `ProductCode` as "Input variable prefix" and "Output Variable Name"

   [image]
3. And finally add a HTTP Request sampler as the child of the ForEach Controller and refer the current product code as `${ProductCode}` where required

Demo:

[image]